# How to use Evernote APIs in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, evernote

I am using Evernote APIs to create custom notepad and as per process I install the cocoapod the the ever note and follow all the steps given in documentation [Evernote Documentation](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios). When I goes to use it EvernoteSDK is not included.

No classes from evernote are visible for me.

Comment: You can use railCloud it. It is written in Objective C but you can integrate in in Swift. It makes your work easy. https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-ios-sdk

Comment: You're probably missing the #import "EvernoteSDK.h" on the files you need it on.

Comment: @Brduca I know importing "EvernoteSDK.h" is essential to use erver not APIs and I include this as well

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are pointing to the old documentation. try the new one [here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios).
It is very simple if you have cocopods file, add:-

```
pod 'evernote-cloud-sdk-ios'
```